# net core gitlab CI throwing message as The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, gitlab

I have a gitlab CI for my .net core api and i want to deploy the api to IIS server, where it is giving the error if the process is already used. The typical solution for this is to stop or recycle the Application pool. which i am doing through the powershell script and it is successfully stopping the pool but still giving the same error as **The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

```
variables:
        publish_path: 'bin\Release\net7.0\publish\'
        application_pool_name: 'testcicd'
        application_name: 'testcicd'
        iis_application_path: 'E:\temp_files\cicdtestpublish'
    stages:
        - build
        - tests
        - deploy
    
    build:
        stage: build
        script:
            - dotnet restore
            - dotnet build --no-restore
            - dotnet publish .\apicicdtest\apicicdtest.csproj -c Release -o $publish_path
        artifacts:
            paths:
                - $publish_path
            expire_in: '1 hrs'
        tags:
            - windows
        only:
            - branches
    
    deploy:
        stage: deploy
        script:
            - |
               if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $application_pool_name).Value -ne 'Stopped'){
                    Write-Output ('Stopping Application Pool: {0}' -f $application_pool_name)
                    Stop-WebAppPool -Name $application_pool_name
               }
            - Copy-Item ($publish_path + "*") -Destination $iis_application_path -recurse -Force -PassThru
            - Start-Sleep -s 5
            - |
                if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $application_pool_name).Value -ne 'Started'){
                    Write-Output ('Starting Application Pool: {0}' -f $application_pool_name)
                    Start-WebAppPool -Name $application_pool_name
                }
        only:
            - branches
        tags:
            - windows
        dependencies:
            - build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the copy item command's below parameter is what I have finally identified as the cause.

```
-recurse -Force -PassThru
```

After I removed it, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like the app is still running. I used to have a similar problem when deploying `.dll` files. You can put a `App_Offline.htm` file in app `wwwroot` directory, and it will be recognized by server. It will attempt to gracefully shut down the app and stop processing incoming requests.

```
New-Item -Path $pathToApp -Name "app_offline.htm" -ItemType "file"

# Provide script commands here to deploy the app

Remove-Item -Path $pathToApp\app_offline.htm
```

Also, 5 seconds may be too short. I personally use 15 seconds, but 10 should also be fine. Depends on the app, obviously.

Read more about `App_Offline.htm` file in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-7.0).